# How to include quotes in comma separated column mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve a comma separated column with single quotes from my table.

Here is what I currently get by selecting the `status` from my table:

```
+-------------------------+
| status                  |
+-------------------------+
| ready,closed            |
| ready,testing,complete  |
+-------------------------+
```

I need to get the following result instead:

```
+-------------------------------+
| status                        |
+-------------------------------+
| 'ready','closed'              |
| 'ready','testing','complete'  |
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT("'", REPLACE(status, ",", "','"), "'") FROM yourtable
```

Here is SQL fiddle for that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6a7ef/12