# Return mysqli query as comma separated values with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following query that is returning:

```
"Code1""Code2""Code3"
```

What I need is for the result to be in CSV format like this:

```
'Code1','Code2','Code3'
```

How do I modify my code to accomplish this?

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "table", "3306");

if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
echo "Unable to connect to database server";
}  

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT code FROM sourcecodes");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mydata = ($row['code']);
    echo json_encode($mydata);
}

$result->free();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: you're returning multiple separate json-encoded strings. that's not valid json, no matter how you slice/dice it. `$mydata[] = $row['code']`, then `json_encode($mydata)` outside the loop would work

Comment: Related: [How to include quotes in comma separated column mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29791745/2943403)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why do you try to use `json_encode`  if you need any kind of CSV format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per every iteration you should be pushing to an array. Once the array is built, you can turn it into json and echo it.

```
$mydata = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mydata[] = $row['code'];
}
$json = json_encode($mydata);
$string = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $json);
echo $string;
```

Comment: This should be least upvoted answer. Meddling with data this way is the very wrong thing to do. There could a `[` symbol in the data, and this code will remove it, making the returned data incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT code FROM sourcecodes");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mydata[] = $row['code'];
   
}
echo "'".implode("','",$mydata)."'";
```

Or you need json_encode?

Comment: Thanks. I dont need json_encode. Your example helped. Now I have the data separated by commas... Code1,Code2,Code3...but just need to add single quotes to each item...'Code1','Code2'...

Comment: This simple  replace  `echo "'".implode("','",$mydata)."'";`

Answer (score -2):

Quite easy to do it this way, by adding a comma to the resulting string.

Get your data in a loop, and add a comma before each next value, excluding the first one:

```
$mydata = "";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT code FROM sourcecodes");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($mydata) {
        $mydata .= ",";
    }
    $mydata .= $row['code'];
}
echo $mydata;
```

you can add any formatting you need, i.e `$mydata .= "'".$row['code']."'";` or anything.

Comment: That looks pretty clumsy. Why not use `implode`, as given in the other answer? Also, `"$count_things"`  would not need any quotes

Comment: @NicoHaase the idea itself is not wrong, and I suggested a better implementation. Doing things in a single loop is always more efficient than in two (while + implode).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).